# Recover a user password on Windows Server 2008

Tags: passwords, user-accounts, windows-server-2008, administrator

Quick question. Is there a way to recover (find out) a users password on Windows Server 2008. I am logged in as admin and I know there are ways to reset passwords, just need to know if I can find out the current password.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are the admin you should just reset their password.

Comment: Looks like I will have to do that. Just wanted to check before I took that route. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. The idea is that you can't see users passwords, even as an administrator, so you can't pretend to be them without them knowing about it. You can reset their password if they lose it, but if you do, they'll know you did.

Comment: You should never know your users passwords, it puts you in a very awkward position if anything happens to their profile /online accounts etc.